# Using XPath to select a descendant node that doesn't have a specified intermediate node

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Using XPath 2.0 (ideally) or 3.0 (an option), I'd like to select a node `C` that is a descendant of `A` as long as the path from `A` to `C` does not contain any `B` nodes.

```
<Root>
  <Other>
    <A>
      <Other>
        <C/> <!--selected-->
      </Other>
      <Other>
        <B>
          <Other>
            <C/> <!--not selected-->
          </Other>
        </B>
      </Other>
    </A>
  </Other>
</Root>
```

`Other` represents 0 or more nested non-`B` nodes.

`A` may have `B` ancestors.

Comment: Well, for the shown example `//A//C[not(ancestor::B)]` would suffice but of course if there can be `B` ancestors of the `A` elements then it doesn't suffice.

Comment: Which version of XPath?

Comment: Yes @MartinHonnen, there can be `B` ancestors of `A`.

Comment: @choroba XPath 2.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath?view=net-7.0

Comment: Apparently not XPath 2.0 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77397462/3051702).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write

```
//A/(.//C except .//B//C)
```

except perhaps if it's a very large document and performance is a concern, in which case I might implement my own transitive closure over `(child::* except child::B)`.

Answer (score 2):

With XPath 2.0, I think `//A//C[not(ancestor::B intersect ancestor::A[1]//B)]` suffices. Note, however, that Microsoft's XPath implementation is XPath 1.0.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Now I just need to understand it. :)

Thanks for the steer on the XPath version. When Microsoft say they use the XPath 2.0 data model, this doesn't imply XPath 2.0 then.

Comment: @fractor, I think when they designed that API  and documented it they were also working on implementing XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0 but in the end pulled that plan in favour of pushing LINQ to XML as Microsoft's alternative to the W3C standards of XPath 2 and XQuery 1.The XmlPrime guys have implemented XPath 2 and by now XPath 3.1 in the context of Microsoft's API, but the Microsoft XPath stack in .NET framework and .NET Core aka .NET 6 or later does only implement XPath 1.0.